# Current Location Indicator HERE SDK Lite Edition

Tags: here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

Have anyone succeeded in adding a current location indicator for HERE SDK Lite version?
In the Premium edition, there's a `PositionIndicator` class to handle that, but I haven't found such thing in HERE Lite Edition. Currently I have to manually added a marker for the current location, which is very inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Lite Edition* does not support a default location indicator. What you do is the correct solution: Add a `MapMarker` and a `MapCircle` as accuracy halo and find the user's location as described [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-lite/4.7.0.0/dev_guide/topics/positioning.html).

The `Navigate Edition` supports default location indicator assets during tracking / tbt use case. It also provides a convenient [HERE Positioning](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.7.0.0/dev_guide/topics/get-locations.html) solution.